# How pass a variable during ajax rendering in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I want to pass a variable to my ajax rendering function.Something like this

```
$this->render('tempcomment/'.$id, 'ajax');
```

and my tempcomment action is

```
public function tempcomment($id) {
    $commentdata = $this->Post->Comment->findByPostid($pid);
    $this->set('commentdata', $commentdata);
}
```

but rendering is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below to start with:

```
public function tempcomment($id) {
                        //   ^ ------ ...
    $commentdata = $this->Post->Comment->findByPostid($pid);
                                                 //    ^--- this is different!
    $this->set('commentdata', $commentdata);
}
```

Comment: Oop's!It's my mistake. I corrected to $pid -> $id. Again nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`render` is used just to decide what view to use in your controller action to render the action. It does not call the action itself

so if you have a code like this

```
public function test() {
    $this->set('foo', 12345);
    $this->render('tempcomment', 'ajax');
}
```

you are just saying that you want to use the `tempcomment` view to render the `test` action but you are not telling cake to actually execute the `tempcomment` action.

so if you want to call the action you have to do by yourself

```
$this->tempcomment($id);
$this->render('tempcomment/'.$id, 'ajax');
```

let me tell you that I don't see any reason to do this and I think that probably there are other ways to do what you are trying to achieve. But I assume you know what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its another work around of what you want to achieve:

```
 public functionc ajax_tempcomment($id){ //just access this action
      $this->redirect('tempcomment/'.$id);
      $this->layout = "ajax";
 }

 public function tempcomment($id) {
     $commentdata = $this->Post->Comment->findByPostid($pid);
     $this->set('commentdata', $commentdata);
 }
```